# oAuth 2.0: Is it possible to share the access_token with different applications?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Is it possible to share the access_token with different applications? I think it's perfectly possible. Once the token is granted, requests are made only by passing the access_token. There is no mechanism to verify the application from which the request is made.

So, if a service places a limit of 100 tokens per app, it would suffice to register two apps and share access_tokens to hold 200 tokens per app.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The oAuth token is a guarantee that you can interact with a Service Provider (SP) on behalf of an Identity (IdP).  So if you are sharing a token between multiple applications you are indicating to the Service Provider that those are all your applications (which is perfectly acceptable), but you can't give Facebook's oAuth Token to Twitter, or use your own LinkedIn Token to modify the account of someone other than you.

Comment: If someone interferes my access_token could access my data? So what advantages does oAuth against basic authentication for security? Stealing the acces_token is as "simple" as stealing the user/password pair.

Comment: Well one big advantage is the owner of the identity can centrally reject oAuth tokens.  And more advanced Identity and Service providers can impose restrictions like expire tokens after 24 hours (I think that's Facebook's stance) or only allow read actions via oAuth while requiring basic auth for anything that might change or delete information.  You have to ask yourself what is more secure, a password that provides full access to anyone who can infer it or a single service token that can be centrally terminated and only exposes a subset of functionality to a potential hacker.